# Twitters json search results returning empty

Tags: json, twitter

I am having trouble access tweets via twitters json search
https://search.twitter.com/search.json?callback=?&rpp=5&q=from:secretdreameruk

The strange this was it was working a few weeks ago, but all of a sudden stopped and is producing no errors.
Viewing the above link in a browser displays the json return, but the results section is empty ("results":[]), even though I have tweeted recently.

At first I thought the usage would be limited per day, but I have had this problem for about a week.

Does anyone know why this has happened?

Thank you.
Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why that seems to be happening though by twitter's [own admission](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search):

> Search is focused in relevance and not completeness. This means that
>   some Tweets and users may be missing from search results. If you want
>   to match for completeness you should consider using the Streaming API
>   instead.

I would use the [following api format](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/user_timeline) instead, it's much more customisable.

```
https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=secretdreameruk&count=5&callback=?
```

Comment: Thank you, the api does look much better, I'll give it a try